# UWP run Exe file with Parameters

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

on UWP, I want to run a Exe file with parameter.
Here is an example.

```
process.exe filename.txt
```

this Command line application process the text file and output a result file as Text.

**My Question is**

How to pass the parameter. I success to run Exe file on UWP, but the input full path for filename maybe wrong and failed.

in ViewModels,

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("spectrum");
```

in Package.appxmanifest

```
  <Extensions>
    <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Assets\identify\process.exe" >
      <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
        <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="spectrum" Parameters="Assets\Identify\filename.txt"/>
      </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
    </desktop:Extension>
  </Extensions>
...
<Capabilities>
<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
</DeviceCapability>
```

Now, I put a file on Assets\identify folder. it is same folder with exe file.
but Exefile can not find the input file.

How should I write in "desktop:ParameterGroup...." ??

Is there anyway to pass Argument in programmatically ?
Honestly, I do not want to write argement in Package.appxmanifest.

**Update 1:**
I tried this too. but can not find the filename.

```
        <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="spectrum" Parameters=".\Assets\Identify\filename.txt"/>
```

Update 2

my external application show this error :

[image]

This mean, My external applicaiton received strange string as input argument.
"*/InvokerPRAID : App Appx/identify/souma.spe"

What is /InvokerPRAID : App ??

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008948/how-to-launch-a-full-trust-desktop-bridge-app-from-uwp-with-arbitrary-paramete/46009106

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch a full-trust (desktop bridge) app from UWP with arbitrary parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008948/how-to-launch-a-full-trust-desktop-bridge-app-from-uwp-with-arbitrary-paramete)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the parameter to the arguments of the Win32 application, the value is in the third argument.

**UWP Package Manifest:**

```
<desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="spectrum" Parameters=".\Assets\Identify\filename.txt"/>
```

**Win 32 Application**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //args[0] = "/InvokerPRAID :"
   //args[1] = "App"
   var fullTrustProcessParam = args[2]; //".\Assets\Identify\filename.txt"
}
```

Comment: how do I pass parms into my UWP app through the public MainWindow initialization method? IE: my XAML UWP app is launched using either a custom web protocol `myProtocol://Launcher?user=userId&eventId=eventId;` or via another app calling `Process.Start("c:/ProgramFiles/MyCompany/MyApp.exe")`