# How to run exe file with parameters in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I recently converted my WPF app to UWP app.

My app needs to run sub-software. I used to run it, in WPF, with `process.run` but it doesn't work in UWP.
I need a way to run the sub-software with parameters which changes every run.

Comment: The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47765108/uwp-run-exe-file-with-parameters) might help

Answer (score -1):

From your executer,

```
Process p= new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "process.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "param1 param2";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

The actual `process.exe`

```
static void Main (string [] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine(args[0]); //prints param1
  Console.WriteLine(args[1]); //prints param2
}
```