# What is 'parameterGroupId' in 'FullTrustProcessLauncher'?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I want to launch an exe passing parameters to it. However, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher#Windows_ApplicationModel_FullTrustProcessLauncher_LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync_System_String_)   doesn't explain how to do that. It just mentions a `parameterGroupId` which is described as

> The parameter group ID for the parameters that will be passed to the
>   launched process.

So how do I provide the exe with parameters?

**EDIT**

I mean that I want a dynamically created value to be passed to the exe as an argument. Not something that I need to compile with the app.

Comment: Did you look at the sample XML? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher#Remarks

Comment: @mjwills Can you please explain that a little bit more. We already know that it needs to be a string identifier of some group. The only thing added there is another string besides that. But what is that other string? I still don't know what I'm supposed to do to pass an `int` `i` to the exe.

Comment: What do you think `<desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="SyncGroup" Parameters="/Sync"/> ` does?

Comment: @mjwills Probably passes "/Sync" as an argument. I want to pass an arbitrary dynamically created argument. If the app decides to launch the process with argument "abc" - then that's what I want it to do.

Comment: I hope this can help.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189353/uwp-how-to-start-an-exe-file-that-is-located-in-specific-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189353/uwp-how-to-start-an-exe-file-that-is-located-in-specific-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. At least not directly.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46009106/939213 .

What this `parameterGroupId` does is something else. It allows to send one of **predefined** parameters. And this `parameterGroupId` just chooses between them.