# How to pass args to a UWP Application with EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" in AppxManifest.xml

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp, appxmanifest

I am trying to set up an `AppxManifest.xml` to launch a Win32 application as a full trust application. Using the snippet below, I am able to `Add-AppxPackage -Register AppxManifest.xml` and then use `Debug > Other Debugging Tools > Debug Installed Application` to debug the application in Visual Studio 2017.

However, I want to pass some arguments to the application when launching it. How can I acomplish this? I don't mind listing them in the `AppxManifest.xml` if that is easiest, I just need to know how.

```
...
<Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="SomeExecutable.exe" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Wrap" Description="Wrap" BackgroundColor="transparent" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch a full-trust (desktop bridge) app from UWP with arbitrary parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008948/how-to-launch-a-full-trust-desktop-bridge-app-from-uwp-with-arbitrary-paramete)

Answer (score -1):

[Protocol associations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#protocol) is what you look for:

> Protocol associations can enable other programs and system components
>   to interoperate with your packaged app. When your packaged application
>   is started by using a protocol, **you can specify specific parameters to
>   pass to its activation event arguments so it can behave accordingly.
>   Parameters are supported only for packaged, full-trust apps**.

```
<Package
  xmlns:uap3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3"
  xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap3, desktop">
  <Applications>
    <Application>
      <Extensions>
        <uap3:Extension
          Category="windows.protocol">
          <uap3:Protocol
            Name="myapp-cmd"
            Parameters="/p " />
        </uap3:Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```